# custom HTML5 audio player addEventListener error

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

var music = document.getElementById('music'); // id for audio element
var duration; // Duration of audio clip
var pButton = document.getElementById('pButton'); // play button
var playhead = document.getElementById('playhead'); // playhead
var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline'); // timeline

// timeline width adjusted for playhead
var timelineWidth = timeline.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth;

// play button event listenter
pButton.addEventListener("click", play);

// timeupdate event listener
music.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);
```

a this point i get error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' or null

please help
ive skipped rest of the code

Comment: please post a minimal working example

Comment: the error you're getting is probably from the lines `pButton.addEventListener` or `music.addEventListener` and it means that the element in question wasn't found previously with `document.getElementById`

Comment: ok thank you very much